# vagrant - Vagrantfile: sync multiple folders

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I have tried the following to sync multiple folders from host to guest machine.
But only one folder is getting synced, the later one.

```
config.vm.synced_folder "host/site1", "/var/www/site1" 

config.vm.synced_folder "host/site2", "/var/www/site2"
```

Comment: Can we see your whole actual Vagrantfile, with the actuals folders?

Comment: Also, knowledge of your host and guest OS will be useful. Based on the tags I'm guessing your host is Windows, but please include a version (eg. 8.1, 10, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newest virtualbox and vagrant versions this is improved and work without problems...